# Iterate over groups in grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to iterate over groups in the following data frame:

```
gop      Family         date         Amount
A          F1        2019-03-06       0.00      
                     2019-04-04       0.00
                     2019-05-07       0.00
B          F1        2019-03-06      -0.02
                     2019-04-04      -25.02
                     2019-05-07      -7.02
           F2        2019-03-06      -40.68
                     2019-04-04       2.76
                     2019-05-07      3525.57
```

I have used the following code:

```py
df_grouped = df.sort_values(['date']).groupby(['gop', 'Family', 'date'])
for group in df_grouped:
    #operations on groups
```

The problem I have is that each group is of type `tuple` which I don't know how to work with. What I want is to consider each group as separate dataframe.

The expected Data frames are:

```
gop      Family         date         Amount
A          F1        2019-03-06       0.00      
                     2019-04-04       0.00
                     2019-05-07       0.00

###############
gop      Family         date         Amount
B          F1        2019-03-06      -0.02
                     2019-04-04      -25.02
                     2019-05-07      -7.02
##############
gop      Family         date         Amount
B           F2        2019-03-06      -40.68
                     2019-04-04       2.76
                     2019-05-07      3525.57
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack tuples to 2 variables - e.g. add `i` for group name and `group` for `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], ['F1', 'F2'], ['2019-03-06', '2019-04-04', '2019-05-07']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['gop', 'Family', 'date'])
```

---

```
df_grouped = df.sort_values(['date']).groupby(['gop', 'Family'])
for i, group in df_grouped:
    print (i)
    print (group)
('A', 'F1')
                       Amount
gop Family date              
A   F1     2019-03-06     0.0
           2019-04-04     0.0
           2019-05-07     0.0
('B', 'F1')
                       Amount
gop Family date              
B   F1     2019-03-06   -0.02
           2019-04-04  -25.02
           2019-05-07   -7.02
('B', 'F2')
                        Amount
gop Family date               
B   F2     2019-03-06   -40.68
           2019-04-04     2.76
           2019-05-07  3525.57
```

Also is possible unpack again tuples created by columns in `groupby`:

```
for (a,b), group in df_grouped:
    print (a)
    print (b)
    print (group)

A
F1
                       Amount
gop Family date              
A   F1     2019-03-06     0.0
           2019-04-04     0.0
           2019-05-07     0.0
B
F1
                       Amount
gop Family date              
B   F1     2019-03-06   -0.02
           2019-04-04  -25.02
           2019-05-07   -7.02
B
F2
                        Amount
gop Family date               
B   F2     2019-03-06   -40.68
           2019-04-04     2.76
           2019-05-07  3525.57
```

Comment: it doesn't work if you add a column (in my case `Amount` column)  that is not used for grouping. The output is a dataframe for every row

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen - hmm, if grouping by `['gop', 'Family', 'date']` it means groups by all unique triples, so in your data is it each row, because `date` are unique per `gop` and `Family`. So what is expected output?

Comment: actually `date` is not unique per `gop` and `family`. I added the expected dataframes to the equestion

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen - So change `.groupby(['gop', 'Family', 'date'])` to `.groupby(['gop', 'Family'])`

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen - Also if still problem. what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: your update is exactly what I was looking for. However do you know why when I use `.groupby(['gop', 'Family', 'date'])` with `first()` I see the grouping correct but when iterating on groups it's different. but when I use `.groupby(['gop', 'Family'])` I see different grouping but when iterating it's what I'm looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194537/discussion-between-mohamed-belahcen-and-jezrael).

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen - it depends what columns are used for grouping - if use `.groupby(['gop', 'Family'])` are used both columns, if use `.groupby(['gop'])` or `.groupby(['Family'])` is used only one column for groups.